# How to receive data from App Settings Azure (webapp) to my webjob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have made an Azure WebJob in c#. I have a web app on Azure, I added my WebJob to my subscription, all good works but in Application Settings I add a new entry, an example:

```
<add key="MyDesiredKey" value="1234" />
```

How can I get value of my key into my application when that runs on azure?

I try like this but not working, in this case no need to have that key in my web config no? When webjob run need to get value from Appsettings from my webapp stored on Azure

```
var keyFromAzureApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDesiredKey"];
```

Comment: Please add a comment when down-voting a question to specify how it can be improved. This is quite clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I get value of my key into my application when that runs on azure?

According to my test if we have no setting on the azure portal, we will get the null value in the Webjob. Please add it on the azure portal, more detail please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

After doing that then all of following ways should work

```
 var myDesiredKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDesiredKey"];
 var environmentmyDesiredKey  = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyDesiredKey");
 var cloudmyDesiredKey = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyDesiredKey");
```

Comment: but it doesn't work for the code inside a webjob for me, though it works for the code inside the web application

Comment: For me inside the web application the Application Setting on Azure portal overwrites the appsettings.json values, but for webjobs it doesn't.  Therefore to change a variable value for webjobs I have to change it e redeploy it.

Answer (score 3):

use CloudConfigurationManager instead as it tries in multiple places with a fallback mechanism.

```
var keyFromAzureApp = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyDesiredKey");
```

Check out [this](http://msdevzone.net/2017/07/18/configurationmanager-vs-webconfigurationmanager-vs-cloudconfigurationmanager/) to know when to use CloudConfigurationManager

Answer (score 2):

As bradbury9 explained you can use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`["my-Key-Value"] for this.

It would be better if you add the application settings in the portal. These will be made available to all the processes on the instance as **Environment variables** at run time.

For **app settings** the name of the corresponding environment variable is prepended with **`APPSETTING_`**.

Here is a blog post which describes this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/