# Read Azure WebApp ApplicationSetting from PowerShell WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-webjobs

I know it is possible to read Application Settings from a `c#` WebJob in a Azure WebApp as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144771/how-to-receive-data-from-app-settings-azure-webapp-to-my-webjob) post.

Basically you can use the `ConfigurationManager` or `CloudConfigurationManager` because the WebJob runs in the same WebApp context, like this:

```
var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
var appCloudSetting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyKey");
```

In my scenario I'm not using a `c#` application but a PowerShell script and I'm looking for a similar solution.
Is it possible to read those Application Settings in a PowerShell WebJob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set Azure App Settings, they become environment variables at runtime. So from your PowerShell WebJob, you can simply use:

```
$Env:YourAppSetting
```

Answer (score 0):

For App Settings, try something like this:

```
$resource = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName YourSite/appsettings -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$resource.Properties
```

And for connection strings:

```
$resource = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName YourSite/connectionstrings -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$resource.Properties
```

The output of webjob applicationsettings is as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the need to specify the ResourceGroup and WebsiteName defeats the generic purpose I need. I want to retrieve the settings of the current WebApp Context.